# X-editable field issue with a single quote

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

With a bootstrap 3, i try to make a single quote appear in x-editable select field as one of the possible choices.

```
<a href="#" class="editable" 
            data-type='select'
            data-value="[{value:'1',text:'I'm happy'},{value:'2',text:'or sad'}]">
  Select  me
</a>
```

In this example I'm trying to change the show "I'm happy" as one of the choices. I give the data in a JSON string through the data-value attribute.

That link is made editable (X-editable JS lib) with this function call:

```
$('.editable').editable({   
    mode: 'popup',
    type: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
    }
 });
```

Click on the link "Select me" and you will see an error in red from X-editable: "Error when loading list". (probably because my quote breaks the JSON structure).

Here´s my problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrunoBp7/yurse4zp/2/)!

Any suggestion to fix this is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using incorrect attribute for source, should be like this:

```
<div style="margin: 150px">
    <a href="#" class="editable" data-type='select' data-value="1" data-source="[{value:'1',text:'I\'m happy'},{value:'2',text:'or sad'}]">Select  me</a>
</div>
```

From [documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/):

> **value**: initial value. Should be defined for select type to store id of shown text.
>   **source**: source for data in select element. If string - considered url for ajax to load items. Otherwise should be json.

And escape your quote with backslash.